# Write C# wrapper for latest Tesseract (Like how tessnet did)

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, tesseract, tessnet2

I have been using tessnet 2.0 for my project for a while now.
But recently I needed to start using a software written by my colleague, and it is not compatible with the tessnet 2.0 dll which uses .NET 2.0. I guess I will have to find a way to write a .NET 4.0 C# wrapper. But I have no knowledge/experience in wrapper at all.

I know all the Tesseract source code can be found from [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), but how do I even use them?

I tried a lot of googling to figure out where and how to start but I am really lost. I have intermediate knowledge in writing C# and C++ codes, it would be really helpful if someone can point me to the right direction. Thank you!

p/s: I would not need the complicated features like neural network, etc.

**Edit 1:
Thanks for the replies! I definitely wasn't aware of the multithreading issue.
I only need to use the OCR to read digits so Tesseract can actually get the job done perfectly.
After discussing with colleagues I have decided to run it externally. Any clue how can I do that?**

Comment: .Net 4.0 should support .Net 2.0 libraries unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The first think you need to know is that Tesseract is not multithreaded. The second thing you need to know is that it is not stable, and is prone to memory leaks and other bugs. Because of these two things, you need to run it out of process. The third is that it is not very good.